# Rails AciveRecord maps datetime value to Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord, fixnum

Problem is following.

Ruby on rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2, thin and Webrick servers.

I have a table with 2 datetime fields. On my computer, when I run from localhost, second field is mapped by Activerecord as `Fixnum`, not `Datetime`. On production and on my friends computer (same code exactly) -- everything is fine. So, instead of date value:

```
Ping.last.stop_till 
=> 2011
```

In database everything is saved fine. Both Webrick and thin show this behavior.
Any ideas?

Comment: So, `Ping.last.stop_till.class.name` is displaying `Fixnum` ?

Comment: Yes. Problem solved! It was outdated libmysql.dll on my computer.